# Using an element within a node-set variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a variable `vHeaders` containing a node-set.

I now want to create a **for-loop**, such that for-each element in `vHeaders`, I'm creating a variable containing another node set:

```
    <xsl:variable name = "vHeaders" select = "DATAPACKET/METADATA/FIELDS/*/@attrname"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$vHeaders">
        <xsl:variable name="blah" select= "."/>
        <xsl:variable name = "vName" select = "DATAPACKET/ROWDATA/*/$blah"/>
        <xsl:value-of select = "vName[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I'm new to XML, and I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the XML structure associated with the elements shown in the XPath of the code?

Comment: Inside of the `for-each` the context node is an attribute node named `attrname` so any attempt to select `DATAPACKET/ROWDATA/*/@blah` relative to that attribute can't select anything as attribute don't have any contained elements. So I suppose you want an absolute path `/DATAPACKET/ROWDATA/*/@blah`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write XSLT code one of the concepts you need to understand is the idea of "context". A path expression such as a/b/c selects nodes relative to some context item; an `xsl:for-each` instruction changes the context item. If the DATAPACKET you want to select when binding `vName` is the same as the DATAPACKET you selected when binding `vHeaders`, then the simplest solution is to move the declaration of `vName` outside the `xsl:for-each`, since it doesn't depend in any way on the new context established by the `xsl:for-each`.

(On the other hand if the `@blah` attribute is intended to have something to do with the `$blah` variable, then there are other problems here as well.)

Comment: Uh oh, the @blah does indeed have something to do with $blah. I'm trying to use the value within the $blah variable as an attribute name when I create the $vName variable

Comment: Then you need `@*[name()=$blah]`